# How do I plot multiple mean diffences between groups into one chart (R)?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I have a post-election dataset where I have asked respondents to rate the tone of the campaign of six candidates (scale 0-10). For each candidate, I want to assess whether ratings of campaign tone differ depending on party identification. I basically have 6 scale variables for campaign tone ratings, one for each leader, and 6 dummy variables for party id, one for each party.

I have created 6 plots, showing mean differences based on party ID for each candidate.

This is the example of the code for each candidate[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCIg1.png):

```
plotR <- data2 %>% 
  group_by(ptID_R) %>% 
  summarise(group_mean = mean(meanIncR, na.rm = TRUE), se = sd(meanIncR, na.rm = TRUE) / sqrt(length(meanIncR))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = group_mean, y = ptID_R, color = ptID_R)) +
  geom_point(size = 2) +
  geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin = group_mean - se, xmax = group_mean + se), height= 0.05) +
  labs(
    title = "Mark Rutte***",
    x = "Incivility (Mean)" ,
    y = "Party ID (1 = VVD)",
    color = ""
  ) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    text = element_text(size=11), 
    plot.title = element_text(face = "bold", size=12, hjust = 0.5),
    axis.title = element_text(size=11),
    plot.margin = unit(c(0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5), "cm"))
```

I have arranged the individual charts into one plot using grid.arrange[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V10Ty.png):

```
plotAll <- grid.arrange(plotW, plotKl, plotR, plotKa, plotH, plotP,
                        nrow = 2, widths = c(1, 1, 1),
                        top = textGrob("Perceptions of Performed Incivility by Party ID",
                        gp = gpar(fontface = "bold", fontsize = 12))
```

However, I would like to show this a little differently. I want to plot all 6 chart together, but in a way that on the y axis I have all leaders, and on the x axis campaign ratings. It should look something like in the picture here linked [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSZ3g.png)

Can anybody help me with this problem? I don't really know how to go about it.
Unfortunately, I cannot share the dataset I am working with, but maybe you can still give me an idea on how to approach this.

Many thanks in advance!
Chiara

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the option you might be looking for is `position = position_dodge()`.

```r
library(ggplot2)

# Make up some dummy data
df <- expand.grid(
  leader = LETTERS[1:6],
  party = factor(c(0, 1))
)
# Dummy scores
set.seed(0)
df$mean <- runif(nrow(df), 0, 10)
df$sd <- runif(nrow(df))

# Use position = position_dodge
ggplot(df, aes(y = leader, colour = party)) +
  geom_point(aes(x = mean),
             position = position_dodge(width = 0.8)) +
  geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin = mean - sd, xmax = mean + sd),
                 position = position_dodge(width = 0.8))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-07-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>